# _Scrape_ text after blockquote bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, blockquote

I have something like this in HTML:

```
<p align="left"><strong><tt>
        some text:</tt></strong><tt> (8/4)</tt><a href="some link"><tt>some other text</tt></a><tt>, (9/4)</tt><a href="some other link"><tt><br/>
        some text:</tt></strong><tt>, (19/6)</tt><!--a href="some link in comment"--><tt>text after comment</tt></p></blockquote></blockquote><tt>, </tt><a href="link i want"><tt>text i want</tt></a><strong><tt><br/>
...
</p>
```

My code in Python:

```
page = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
rounds = soup.find('p', align="left")
matches_links = rounds.find_all('a')
```

I get all link to SOME COMMENT and text after. I can't get anything after `</blockquote></blockquote>`. These two blockquotes are invisible in page code, only when I debugging my Python code I can see it in `soup`. In `soup` I have all HTML code, but in `rounds` code ends on `<tt>text after comment</tt></p>`.

Is any way to get "link i want" and "text i want"?

Comment: Looks like the data you are looking for is dynamically added to the DOM. You should consider using a headless browser scraping  using a tool like selenuim

Comment: "but in rounds code ends on <tt>text after comment</tt></p>", This is because your <p align='left'> tag ends there

Comment: @GaganTK you're right, I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the HTML code, you will see that there's `</p>` before `</blockquote></blockquote>`. That means your variable `rounds` doesn't contain your link that you want. Search for next `<a>` after this `<p>` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<p align="left"><strong><tt>
        some text:</tt></strong><tt> (8/4)</tt><a href="some link"><tt>some other text</tt></a><tt>, (9/4)</tt><a href="some other link"><tt><br/>
        some text:</tt></strong><tt>, (19/6)</tt><!--a href="some link in comment"--><tt>text after comment</tt></p></blockquote></blockquote><tt>, </tt><a href="link i want"><tt>text i want</tt></a><strong><tt><br/>
...
</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

matched_link = soup.select_one('p[align="left"] ~ a')
print(matched_link)
```

Prints:

```
<a href="link i want"><tt>text i want</tt></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, of course you have right. But your solution doesn't work for me, `matched_link` is empty. Could you please explain me what exactly `'p[align="left"] ~ a'` mean?

Comment: @dylo `p[align="left"] ~ a` is CSS selector, it will select next `<a>` tag preceded by a <p align="left"> element. You can try to `print(soup.find_all('a'))` and see, if the desired `<a>` tag is really there.